# Troubleshooting: How can I get Git to use VS Code when making a commit?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh, iterm2

I recently installed Oh My Zsh and VS code. Whenever I enter `git commit` it doesn't open up code, instead it displays the following error message:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot run code: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'code'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I am able to just run code by entering `code` in the terminal.

---

Steps taken:

I've added the following line to my .zshrc

```
# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)
plugins=(... vscode)
```

I've run this line:

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

I've added these lines in my settings.json in Code

```
    "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/zsh"
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your output, which is:

```
error: cannot run code: No such file or directory
```

`code` is not available in your $PATH environment variable. That can be easily solved:

1. CTRL+SHIFT+P in VSCode (or CMD+SHIFT+P on Mac) -- this opens the Command Palette.
2. Type something like "code path", or the exact command you want to execute, which is: `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH.`

And done, that should do the trick.

Specific to Zsh, my `.zshrc` file also has this line:

```
export EDITOR="code -w"
```

But this might not be relevant in the context of Git, it's useful for other binaries that use VSCode as editor.